# Exponential Functions $e^{-2x}$

Tags: exponential-function

> sketch the graph of the following function

$f(x) = e^{-2x}$ for $x \in \mathbb R$

this what i got,

y-intercept $x=0$ implies $y=\cfrac{1}{e^{2\times 0}}$ therefore $y=1$

and I have used the fact that $t= -2x$ $\rightarrow -\infty$  as $x \rightarrow \infty$

by the properties  of the Natural Exponential Function:

$\displaystyle\lim_{x \to \infty} e^x=\infty$

$\displaystyle\lim_{x \to \infty} e^{-2x}=0$

$\displaystyle\lim_{x \to -\infty} e^{t}=0$

Therefore, I draw the curve graph with $y$-intercept coordinates $(0,1)$ and approaches zero.

but my prof said it's wrong. he commented = $e^x$ cannot be zero.

Could you please explain to me about this?...

Comment: "Approaches zero when $x\to+\infty$" $\ne$ "Equals zero at some $x$". Did you make the graph of $y=e^{-x}$ actually *meet* the line $y=0$ at some point?

Comment: Then we have to find a reason why your professor mentioned the fact that $e^x$ is never zero.

Comment: A proof of what? The assertion of your professor is correct, the mystery, so far, is why they think it invalidates your solution.

Comment: @purugin We all want to help you but please be clarify your objective: Is the goal simply "sketch the graph of the following function"?

Comment: yes just the graph .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your professor is correct (as usual) he describes asymptotic behaviour - namely $y=0$ is a horizontal asymptote for $e^{-2x}$. Sketch the graph of $e^{-2x}$ to see this. Firstly you know how to sketch the graph of $e^x$ right? You then apply linear transformations which consist of a horizontal reflection in the $y$-axis and then a stretch of scale factor $1/2$ parallel to the $x$-axis. Does this make sense? If not let me know and I will explain further.

Comment: @purugin yes you're right, but there is still an asymptote at $y=0$

Comment: pls check the link [link](https://www.symbolab.com/solver/functions-graphing-calculator/f%5Cleft(x%5Cright)%3De%5E%7B-2x%7D/?origin=button)

Comment: @purugin I have checked the link purugin, and nice math-site might I add. But I fail to see the relevance of it with respect to this question?

Comment: that's the same graph what i draw. but the prof said it's wrong.

Comment: i can;t i don't have enough reputation for the up-vote.

Comment: Choose domain -1< x < 1 so the graph will be visible at least.